# how to make tree map descending sort show duplicate values

Tags: java, sorting, netbeans, search-engine, treemap

My code sorts a tree map but it do not print duplicate values it also show one of these duplicate values. Can I change it or no? if no, what can I do instead?

```
TreeMap<Double,String> hm=new TreeMap<Double,String>(Collections.reverseOrder());

hm.put(0.1,"sara"); 
hm.put(0.13,"nahla");
hm.put(0.13,"saeed");
hm.put(0.2,"omar");
hm.put(0.5,"olaa");
hm.put(0.5,"noha");

Set set = hm.entrySet();
    Iterator i2 = set.iterator();
   while(i2.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i2.next();
      System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
      System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
```

the output is:

```
0.5: noha
0.2: omar
0.13: saeed
0.1: sara
```

and I want to be like this:

```
0.5: noha
0.5: olaa
0.2: omar
0.13: saeed
0.13: nahla
0.1: sara
```

Comment: Do you just need to flip it so the name is the key?

Comment: my code is dynamic I do not know when keys are equal to each other. This code is an example since the original one is complicated a little bit.

Comment: I think you could put the name as the key and the value of the number.  Then if you want it sorted by the number you can sort the map by the value instead of key by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMap` doesnt allow duplicates so instead use `LinkedMultiValueMap` from 
`org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap` to store and the then sort it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

public class ds {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MultiValueMap<Double, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<Double, String>();
    map.add(8.9, "g");
    map.add(4.6, "h");
    map.add(10.5, "a");
    map.add(10.5, "b");
    map.add(9.6, "c");
    map.add(8.6, "d");
    map.add(8.6, "e");
    map.add(8.0, "f");
    map.add(2.8, "i");

    MultiValueMap<Double, String> filteredMap = filter(5, map);
    System.out.println(filteredMap.toString());

}

public static MultiValueMap<Double, String> filter(int numberOfResults,
        MultiValueMap<Double, String> map) {
    MultiValueMap<Double, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<Double, String>();

    List<Double> keys = new ArrayList<Double>(map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(keys, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (Double key : keys) {
        if (result.size() <= numberOfResults) {
            result.put(key, map.get(key));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: you need to add spring framework dependencies in your pom.xml, then you can import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;